# Нужно вывести перевёрнутый прямоугольный треугольник

Tags: java

у меня есть код, который выводит:

```
43210

4321

432

43

4
```

Мне нужно, чтобы он выводил:

```
43210

3210

210

10

0
```

В целом, нужно, чтобы код печатал:
(*на вход поступает целое чётное число, в примере оно равно 10*).

```
    0

   01

  012

 0123

01234

     43210

     3210

     210

     10

     0
```

Вот мой код для первого треугольника:

```
public static void Triangle(int s){
        if (s % 2 == 0){
            int last_number = (s / 2) - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= last_number; i++){
                for (int k = last_number; k > i; k--){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                    System.out.print(j);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот код для второго:

```
public static void InvertedTriangle(int s){
        if (s % 2 == 0) {
            int last_number = (s / 2) - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= last_number; i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < last_number + 1; k++){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int j = last_number; j >= i; j--){
                    System.out.print(j);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ну может быть немного собраться, подумать и сообразить что нужно поменять, чтобы выводило так как надо. Ведь тут же элементарно все

Comment: `for (int j = last_number - i; j >= 0; j--)`